# ArcObjects Custom Tool for a VB App

Tags: arcobjects, c#, visual-studio

We have an old VB6 app that uses the map, toolbar and toc controls.  On the toolbar, we've added the custom menu so users can add other built-in tools or tools they've created.  One of our customers would like us to build a couple of custom tools for them.  They are using version 10.0 and most users will only have the engine runtime installed.  The walkthroughs that I've seen seem to deal more with ArcGIS Desktop and tools built using ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns won't install on a machine that doesn't have Desktop.  Our customer wants one tool that will query the "Loc_Num" field against a specific set of layers and another that will do an address lookup.  I've spent about 5 days on this and have gone through numerous walkthroughs/code samples and have gotten nowhere.

Comment: Can you post examples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Won't install on a machine that doesn't have ArcGIS Desktop:  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Walkthrough_Building_custom_UI_elements_using_add_ins/0001000001ms000000/

Was able to install on machine, but didn't actually draw any lines:  http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004n5000000

Comment: The big difference between an addin and a runtime is that you've got no application... there is an option to create a standalone application in the project creation wizard which should work with runtime but any interactivity is probably too difficult if you're struggling at this point. I'd tell them they need to have ArcGis or your existing tools wont work - too bad, so sad, but that's the way it is. Your only other option is to create a form that creates and shows a new IActiveView, IMap etc.. that's **a lot of work**